# ADB process hang while trying to run 'adb reboot' over ADB WLAN connection

Tags: android, shell, adb

this is my steps:

> adb connect 'my android IP address'
>
> connected
>
> adb reboot //in this step my phone is rebooting and the process is hang.

What can be the problem, is there any fix or workaround?

When i working on ADB with USB cable it's working well.

thanks

Comment: I've found @chris-stratton answer to be pretty accurate here; the connection is never closed.  Assuming you're running linux, I've been tinkering with the following workaround using something like `adb -s 192.168.2.51:5555 reboot & ( sleep 5 && adb disconnect 192.168.2.51 )` which fires the reboot and allows a bit of time to elapse, then forcefully kills the connection to that specific device.

Answer (score 4):

Somewhat speculation, but `adb reboot` may shut the phone down abruptly enough that the ADBD on the phone never gets to properly close the TCP connection to the ADB server on your development machine.  This would be a lot like the way "hung" TCP connections can result from pulling out a network cable - TCP is designed to survive intermittent communication failures, and so doesn't give up on the possibility of the other end answering until a fairly substantial amount of time (in human terms) has passed.

It's entirely plausible that the ADB server isn't written to take into account the combination of two features which are even individually a bit on the obscure side - TCP connection with rebooting.

If that is the case, your practical options may be to have something kill the ADB server immediately after issuing the reboot, or else modify ADB (it's open source after all) to more intelligently handle this, for example automatically disconnecting after a second or two of non-response if it has issued a reset command.